# Regret Minimization with Hidden Markov Processes

Tags: bayesian, optimization, markov-process, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

Consider a hidden Markov process with two states $\{0, 1\}$ represented with $Z_t$. The transition matrix is unknown, although we can assume it's strongly diagonal (i.e. slow-switching).

At any time, we can observe $Y_t$, where we have:

$
p(Y_t|Z_t) \sim \begin{cases} 
      \text{Ber}\;(p) & Z_t = 0 \\
      0 & Z_t = 1.
   \end{cases}
$

That is, there is a way of *indirectly* observing $Z_t$.

Depending on whether or not we **choose to observe** $Y_t$ and the state of $Z_t$, we have the following Loss function:

$
L(D_t | Z_t) \sim \begin{cases} 
      L_\text{ Used. It was Off.} & D_t = 1 \;\& \; Z_t = 0 \\
      L_\text{ Used. It was On.} & D_t = 1 \; \& \; Z_t = 1 \\
      L_\text{Not used.} & D_t = 0, 
   \end{cases}
$

where $D_t$ represents our decision to whether or not observe $Y_t$ at time $t$.

---

Our goal is to **minimize** regret (expected total loss), by making the best possible decisions $D_t$ on whether or not we observe $Y_t$ over time.

We can assume:

$L_\text{ Used. It was On.}$ < $L_\text{Not used.}$ < $L_\text{ Used. It was Off.}$

---

**Intuition**:
 $Z_t$ represents the state of a resource that we *need* to use (observing = using). If the resource is alive ($Z_t=1$), it's all good, and we can use it ($D_t=1$), but if it isn't ($Z_t=0$), and we use it, we incur a high penalty.

Note that if *even* we **choose** to observe $Y_t$, we may fail to *directly* observe the state of $Z_t$ (as reflected by $\text{Ber}(p)$), since our "detection" mechanism is unreliable. However, we **will** incur a different penalty depending on the actual state of $Z_t$, and not on what we observe in $Y_t$.

---

This problem could be formulated as [multi-armed bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) (K=2) so I could use e.g. [probability-matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_matching) approaches (e.g. [Thompson Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling)) but there are some specific types of assumptions we are making of the bandits here, since there is a hidden Markov Process that controls the underlying reward of observing $Y_t$.

Has this type of conditional multi-armed bandits been studied in the literature? Do they have a name?

Comment: At first blush, it would seem you could formalize this as a partially observable MDP. But, I've only ever seen POMDP observation functions expressed as a function of the $s'$, i.e. the next state, rather than the current one. (Your intuition paragraph somewhat confuses me—when the agent acts, it decides whether to check and then gets a probabilistic observation if $z = 0$, but gets a reward based on the state of $z$, is that right? Why is the observation probabilistic—is the agent not privy to the reward?)

Comment: Thanks @SeanEaster! I have expanded the intuition section to explain why our observation $Y_t$ is probabilistic on $Z_t$.